# GWTP Rebind throwing IllegalArgumentException (ProxyGenerator) after GWT 2.7.0 upgrade

Tags: gwt, illegalargumentexception, gwtp

I'm trying to upgrade an older GWT 2.5.1 project that was semi-retrofitted with GWTP 1.0.2 to GWT 2.7.0, but but I'm running into an error I just can't figure out.  I've googled and googled, I've rearranged project dependencies, and still I get the same error when doing a mvn gwt:compile, below:

```
Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.example.foo.client.administration.AdminPresenter.AdminProxy'
       Rebinding com.example.foo.client.administration.AdminPresenter.AdminProxy
          Invoking generator com.gwtplatform.mvp.rebind.ProxyGenerator
             [ERROR] Generator 'com.gwtplatform.mvp.rebind.ProxyGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'com.example.foo.client.administration.AdminPresenter.AdminProxy'
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.AnnotationProxyFactory$AnnotationProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationProxyFactory.java:248)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.value(Unknown Source)
  at com.gwtplatform.mvp.rebind.ProxyPlaceOutputter.findGatekeeperMethod(ProxyPlaceOutputter.java:144)
  at com.gwtplatform.mvp.rebind.ProxyPlaceOutputter.initSubclass(ProxyPlaceOutputter.java:113)
  at com.gwtplatform.mvp.rebind.ProxyOutputterBase.init(ProxyOutputterBase.java:82)
  at com.gwtplatform.mvp.rebind.TabContentProxyPlaceOutputter.initSubclass(TabContentProxyPlaceOutputter.java:57)
  at com.gwtplatform.mvp.rebind.ProxyOutputterBase.init(ProxyOutputterBase.java:82)
  at com.gwtplatform.mvp.rebind.ProxyOutputterFactory.create(ProxyOutputterFactory.java:78)
  at com.gwtplatform.mvp.rebind.ProxyGenerator.generate(ProxyGenerator.java:89)
  at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:760)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:160)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:265)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:87)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createStaticRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:485)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:443)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:576)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:306)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:248)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:128)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:49)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContext.traverse(JModVisitor.java:95)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemove(JModVisitor.java:351)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:92)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:149)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JIfStatement.traverse(JIfStatement.java:53)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContext.traverse(JModVisitor.java:95)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemove(JModVisitor.java:351)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:92)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:149)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:145)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:83)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:600)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:569)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:1505)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:870)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.unifyJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1305)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.constructJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1038)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:954)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:303)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:38)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:286)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:206)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:158)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:120)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:127)
```

This is occuring for every presenter it appears - it's a fairly large project, and I'm seeing over a dozen versions of the same message, each regarding a different Presenter/Proxy.
    One possible cause / twist is that the presenters / views / proxies were manually built / retro-fitted after the fact - it was previously a plain GWT project, and they used a separate GWTP-created project as an example.  This has worked for the last 2 yrs using GWTP .7 - 1.0.2 on GWT 2.5.1, but somehow it appears to be breaking for the 2.7.0 upgrade.
    I tried upgrading the project to GWTP 1.3.1, but it made no difference.
    I've tried rearranging dependencies - gwt-user fist, gwtp-all first, it made no difference.

After a string of many of the previous errors, there are also a

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderWriter.<init>(Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/typeinfo/JClassType;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/typeinfo/TypeOracle;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/MortalLogger;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/FieldManager;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/messages/MessagesWriter;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/DesignTimeUtils;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/UiBinderContext;ZZLjava/lang/String;)V

error, which in other modules I've been able to fix by moving gwt-user to the top of the dependencies, but it isn't working here.  It's hard to tell which errors are really breaking things, and ideally I'd fix them all.
```

I'm also getting another, certainly related error:

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'gen/com/example/foo/client/reports/com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java'
       [ERROR] Line 36: Failed to resolve 'com.example.foo.client.reports.ReportsPresenter.ReportsProxy' via deferred binding
    Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.example.foo.client.students.StudentsPresenter.StudentsProxy'
       Rebinding com.example.foo.client.students.StudentsPresenter.StudentsProxy
          Invoking generator com.gwtplatform.mvp.rebind.ProxyGenerator
             [ERROR] Generator 'com.gwtplatform.mvp.rebind.ProxyGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'com.example.foo.client.students.StudentsPresenter.StudentsProxy'
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@8eb6f8d
```

It is GWT-compiling in eclipse, but in regular dev mode I get this stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] [FooModule] Uncaught exception escaped
com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Deferred binding failed for 'com.example.foo.client.FooMainTabHolderView$Binder' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:203)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEventFromSource(SimpleEventBus.java:96)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.PresenterWidget.fireEvent(PresenterWidget.java:281)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.RevealContentEvent.fire(RevealContentEvent.java:53)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.Presenter.revealInParent(Presenter.java:400)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.Presenter.forceReveal(Presenter.java:277)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyPlaceAbstract.manualReveal(ProxyPlaceAbstract.java:302)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyPlaceAbstract$3$1.execute(ProxyPlaceAbstract.java:282)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Task$.executeScheduled$(SchedulerImpl.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.runScheduledTasks(SchedulerImpl.java:183)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.flushPostEventPumpCommands(SchedulerImpl.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Flusher.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:78)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:72)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:341)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:137)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:589)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:299)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:72)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:296)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:551)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:368)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.example.foo.client.FooMainTabHolderView$Binder' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.createImpl(GWT.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:86)
    at com.example.foo.client.com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.get_Key$type$com$example$foo$client$FooMainTabHolderView$Binder$_annotation$$none$$(com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java:229)
    at com.example.foo.client.com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.get_Key$type$com$example$foo$client$FooMainTabHolderView$_annotation$$none$$(com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java:244)
    at com.example.foo.client.com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.get_Key$type$com$example$foo$client$FooMainTabHolderPresenter$FooTabView$_annotation$$none$$(com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java:56)
    at com.example.foo.client.com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.get_Key$type$com$example$foo$client$FooMainTabHolderPresenter$_annotation$$none$$(com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java:195)
    at com.example.foo.client.com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment$3.get(com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java:216)
    at com.example.foo.client.com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment$3.get(com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java:1)
    at com.gwtplatform.common.client.StandardProvider.get(StandardProvider.java:48)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyImpl.getPresenter(ProxyImpl.java:45)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.RevealContentHandler.onRevealContent(RevealContentHandler.java:52)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.RevealContentEvent.dispatch(RevealContentEvent.java:77)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.RevealContentEvent.dispatch(RevealContentEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEventFromSource(SimpleEventBus.java:96)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.PresenterWidget.fireEvent(PresenterWidget.java:281)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.RevealContentEvent.fire(RevealContentEvent.java:53)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.Presenter.revealInParent(Presenter.java:400)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.Presenter.forceReveal(Presenter.java:277)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyPlaceAbstract.manualReveal(ProxyPlaceAbstract.java:302)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyPlaceAbstract$3$1.execute(ProxyPlaceAbstract.java:282)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Task$.executeScheduled$(SchedulerImpl.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.runScheduledTasks(SchedulerImpl.java:183)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.flushPostEventPumpCommands(SchedulerImpl.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Flusher.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:78)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:72)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:341)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:137)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:589)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:299)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:72)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:296)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:551)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:368)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderWriter.&lt;init&gt;(Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/typeinfo/JClassType;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/typeinfo/TypeOracle;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/MortalLogger;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/FieldManager;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/messages/MessagesWriter;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/DesignTimeUtils;Lcom/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/UiBinderContext;ZZLjava/lang/String;)V
    at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator.generateOnce(UiBinderGenerator.java:187)
    at com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator.generate(UiBinderGenerator.java:135)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:760)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:160)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ShellModuleSpaceHost.rebind(ShellModuleSpaceHost.java:152)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:613)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:483)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.createImpl(GWT.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:86)
    at com.example.foo.client.com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.get_Key$type$com$example$foo$client$FooMainTabHolderView$Binder$_annotation$$none$$(com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java:229)
    at com.example.foo.client.com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.get_Key$type$com$example$foo$client$FooMainTabHolderView$_annotation$$none$$(com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java:244)
    at com.example.foo.client.com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.get_Key$type$com$example$foo$client$FooMainTabHolderPresenter$FooTabView$_annotation$$none$$(com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java:56)
    at com.example.foo.client.com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.get_Key$type$com$example$foo$client$FooMainTabHolderPresenter$_annotation$$none$$(com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java:195)
    at com.example.foo.client.com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment$3.get(com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java:216)
    at com.example.foo.client.com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment$3.get(com_example_foo_client_gin_ClientGinjector_ClientGinjectorGinjector_fragment.java:1)
    at com.gwtplatform.common.client.StandardProvider.get(StandardProvider.java:48)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyImpl.getPresenter(ProxyImpl.java:45)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.RevealContentHandler.onRevealContent(RevealContentHandler.java:52)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.RevealContentEvent.dispatch(RevealContentEvent.java:77)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.RevealContentEvent.dispatch(RevealContentEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEventFromSource(SimpleEventBus.java:96)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.PresenterWidget.fireEvent(PresenterWidget.java:281)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.RevealContentEvent.fire(RevealContentEvent.java:53)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.Presenter.revealInParent(Presenter.java:400)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.Presenter.forceReveal(Presenter.java:277)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyPlaceAbstract.manualReveal(ProxyPlaceAbstract.java:302)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyPlaceAbstract$3$1.execute(ProxyPlaceAbstract.java:282)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Task$.executeScheduled$(SchedulerImpl.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.runScheduledTasks(SchedulerImpl.java:183)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.flushPostEventPumpCommands(SchedulerImpl.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Flusher.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:78)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:72)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:341)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:137)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:589)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:299)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:72)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:296)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:551)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:368)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and in super dev mode I get a similar, but slightly different stacktrace that won't fit here.

Any ideas / suggestions?

Comment: GinUiBinder is an issue between GWT 2.7 + most GWTP versions. It's fixed in GWTP 1.4-SNAPSHOT. I suggest you update to GWT 2.6.1 first. Also, is there any stacktrace with these errors?

Comment: I'd seen references to GinUiBinder, but I'd gotten the idea it was a separate inherit / process, not the default.  Was I wrong about that?  There were definitely stacktraces - many of them heh.  I'll add them tomorrow

Comment: How many EntryPoints do you have?

Comment: only one entry point